# ajax json returns syntaxerror:unexpected token , struggling to figure out it for few days

Tags: ajax, json, parse-error

Using jQuery,php,mysql ,I wrote the program to
get the ueprice :

(1)After got the  price successfuly
    $prices = array();
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
        $ueprice = intval($row[0]);
        $pricetotal = $ueprice * $suryou;
    $selprice = round($pricetotal*$crate);
    $prices =array(
    'unitp' => $ueprice,
    'sump' => $pricetotal,
    'sellp' => $selprice
        );
(2) return the  $prices using json_encode
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($prices);
     exit;

(3)javascript which calling php is :
    $(function(){
    setPrices1d();
    $("#selectQuantity1d").on("change", setPrices1d);
    });

```
 function setPrices1d() {   

$(document).ready(function()     
{    

     var grn = $('#main1d').val();      //get rank    
     var ghn = $('#sub1d option:selected').text();    //get hinban    
     var gkn = $('#detail1d').val();     //get kinou    
     var gch = $('#curtainH1d').val();     //get curtain height    
     var gcw = $('#curtainW1d').val();     //get curtain width    
     var gcr = $('#sellingRate1d').val();     //get customer_rate   
     var gsu = $('#selectQuantity1d').val();     //get suryou   

             var q = encodeURIComponent("drape");    
             var url = 'jsonprice.php?rank=' + grn + '&categ=' + q + '&hinban=' 
                        + ghn +        '&kinou=' + gkn + '&curtainh=' + gch +    
                        '&curtainw=' + gcw + '&crate=' + gcr + '&suryou=' + gsu;    
         $.ajax({       
         type: "GET",        
         url: url,    

         dataType: "json",    
        /**  
          * Ajax通信が成功した場合に呼び出されるメソッド    
          */  
         success: function(data) {myObject=JSON.parse(data);}    
        {    
             //結果が0件の場合    
             if(data == null) alert('データが0件でした');    
             //返ってきたデータの表示    

             var $unitprice = $('#unitPrice1d');    
             var $sumprice =  $('#sumTotal1d');    
            var $sellprice = $('#sellingPrice1d');    
             // clear input area  
            $unitprice.empty();    
            $sumprice.empty();    
            $sellprice.empty();    
            //set prices into text area   

            $unitprice.val(data[0].unitp);    
            $sumprice.val(data[0].sump);    
            $sellprice.val(data[0].sellp);

                 },    

        /**    
         * Ajax通信が失敗場合に呼び出されるメソッド   
         */
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)   
        {   
         alert('エラー : HttpReq= ' + XMLHttpRequest + ' textStatus =' +  textStatus + ' errThrown =' + errorThrown + ' errThrown.message  =' + errorThrown.message + ' HttpReq.status =' + XMLHttpRequest.status);    
        }   
     });      
 });
```

}

(4)above $.ajax returns the following error:
    HttpReq= [object Object]
    errThrown = SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
    Httpreq.status = 200

(5) To figure out this error I spent for few days , but not resolved yet.
 Using the google chrome,
network response seems to me good:
Network Resonponce
 array(8) { 
   ["rank"]=>
   string(1) "S"
   ["categ"]=>
   string(12) "drape"
   ["hinban"]=>
   string(7) "TKR8001"
   ["kinou"]=>
   string(10) "2倍ヒダ"
   ["curtainh"]=>
   string(6) "45-120"
   ["curtainw"]=>
   string(5) "50-75"
    ["crate"]=>
   string(4) "0.90"
   ["suryou"]=>
   string(1) "3"
 }

{"unitp":30000,"sump":90000,"sellp":81000}

I greately appricate your advice for this parse error,
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you try using curl to call your server to get your results back, I always find it useful to check exactly what is coming back using curl.  E.g curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user":{"first_name":"firstname","last_name":"lastname","email":"email@email.com","password":"app123","password_confirmation":"app123"}}'  http://localhost:3000/api/1/users

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error(Syntax Error:unexpected token),so I would like to describe the cause.

(1)The error was in the codings of the jsonprice.php.
 For debugging purposes, following two code were written in it.
 print "
sql= $sql"
 var_dump($array)

Syntax error was stopped when I comment out these two codings.

(2)After comment out these codings,
 I got another error:
 (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unitp' of undefined)

The cause of this error was the array description.
 $prices = array
 $prices[] = array  <- [] is needed

After that,I get the proper results.

Comment: Your question and answer are really hard to read because the lack formatting. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and especially http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code.